# How to override forgot password method in laravel auth?

Tags: laravel-5.5

Hiii Friends, I want to override a method like forgot password default to override forgot the password to reset the password through an email link.
But I don't have any idea.
can anyone help me to give me some suggestion or hint?

Answer (score 0):

You may go to your `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController` and add your methods. You may also need to read and understand how the Reset password works by default in Laravel here: `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords` and `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RedirectsUsers`.

You may also read the Laravel's Authentication Quickstart,  https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication#authentication-quickstart.

There are other methods you can do actually, like adding `reset()` method on your `ResetPasswordController` or adding an event listener (https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication#events).

Comment: Thanks for helping me, but what can do in particular method like matching with token or reset the password for go to with mail link?

Comment: Whatever you wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend the Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordBroker Class from Laravel’s Authentication module.

But Even If you Extend this Class in your Project, It won’t work because PasswordBroker Class is referred by PasswordBrokerManager which is registered in ServiceProvider. So there are a couple of steps involved.

Follow this guide for detailed steps

https://www.5balloons.info/extending-passwordbroker-class-laravel-5/